# New buildable angular library can not be build

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

so... I have the latest version of nx (11.1.5) running in a new workspace (`--preset empty`) running and I want to add a new buildable angular library.

`nx g @nrwl/angular:library --buildable --style scss --name my-lib`

The library is created and seems to be alright. Next, I want to build that library without changing something on the code using:

`nx build my-lib`

My expectation is, that this runs through without any problems. Doesn't make sense to build an empty module, but should work, right?

**But** the build exits with the following error message:

```
No provider for InjectionToken ng.v5.stylesheetProcessor! (InjectionToken nx.v1.packageTransform -> InjectionToken nx.v1.entryPointTransform -> InjectionToken ng.v5.compileNgcTransform -> InjectionToken ng.v5.stylesheetProcessor)
```

Even when I add components and export them or import the module in an app, the error shows up.

What am I missing here? Is this a bug?

It's also reproducible in the example repo: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples

Greetings

Comment: I have same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a fix on the way...

https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/4578

Comment: Thanks. I have only looked for issues regarding that.

Comment: I get no errors if I stay on Angular ~11.0.9, so maybe downgrading will help in the meantime.

Comment: Nx 11.2.0 has been released with the fix in it. However, I didn't find the time to test it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: re-build package-lock.json

I was getting this same error but when chasing the commit that caused it using `git bisect`, the commit didn't have any scss changes at all. It had some unexpected `package-lock.json` changes, so I reverted that file with `git checkout <before broken> .\package-lock.json` followed by `npm install`, and `npx ng run build`, it succeeded. My new `package-lock.json` had a lot of new changes, that were not in the broken one, and these changes didn't get included with a `npm install` without reverts to that `package-lock.json`. These new changes included a downgrade of `sass`, as a dependency of `ng-package`, from `^1.32.5` to `^1.26.0`. `ng-package` itself got downgraded from `11.1.2` to `11.0.3`